# How to add configuration to a flutter project i take from Github

Tags: android, flutter, github

[image]
[image]

tried to add configuration with the normal way
and how to make the same configuration run in all project i made
if someone face the same problem before please help

Comment: all you need it is set name e.g. main.dart and provide path to your main.dart class(in Dart file text field)